# keras lstm seq2seq example Keyword argument not understood return_state on windows

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow

I am running this example code ( seq2seq built on Keras)form https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py.
This code runs correctly on my Ubuntu. But an error occured when I ran the same code on my Windows.
It says:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Number of samples: 10000
>   Number of unique input tokens: 73
>   Number of unique output tokens: 86
>   Max sequence length for inputs: 17
>   Max sequence length for outputs: 42
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "h:/eclipse_workspace/Keras_DL/src/seq2seq/lstm_seq2seq.py", line 125, in 
>       encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state = True)
>     File "D:\software\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "D:\software\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 949, in **init**
>       super(LSTM, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>     File "D:\software\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 191, in **init**
>       super(Recurrent, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>     File "D:\software\anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 281, in **init**
>       raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
>   TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'return_state')

I found that return_state do exists in
  `keras.layers.recurrent.Recurrent(return_sequences=False, return_state=False, go_backwards=False, stateful=False, unroll=False, implementation=0)`

Can anyone tell me how can I run this demo correctly on Windows?

My system info:
 - OS : Windows 10 64 bit
 - python 3.5.2 64 bit
 - cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v5.1
 - keras 2.04 tensorflow-gpu 1.1.0

Comment: What are the versions on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Keras version is too old. `return_state` is added in Keras 2.0.5. I suggest you install the latest version from GitHub, since the example code you're running has been added to the library less than 24 hours ago.